# Manage Google Adwords Feeds by using AdWords API (PHP Client Library)

Tags: google-ads-api

How I can manage my feed in Google AdWords using php client lib of AdWords Api? I need to change data in some feed items but I can't find appropriate code examples in php how to do it.
Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Examples are available in the documentation of the PHP code itself, here's one that add feedItems in a given feed: 
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201506/Extensions/AddSitelinksUsingFeeds.php

When you are updating, make sure you use the "SET" operator instead of "ADD".

Basically, what you want to do is the following:

```
foreach ($feedData as $data) {
    $feedItemClass = new \FeedItem();
    $feedItemClass->attributeValues = [
        // INT64, refer to (1) for more info
        new FeedItemAttributeValue(1, (int)$data['id']),
        // StringValues
        new FeedItemAttributeValue(2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, $data['urlLangs']),
        // String
        new FeedItemAttributeValue(3, null, null, null, $data['name']),
        new FeedItemAttributeValue(4, null, null, null, $data['imageUrl']),
        new FeedItemAttributeValue(5, null, null, null, $data['price']),
    ];

    $feedItemClassOperation = new FeedItemOperation();
    $feedItemClassOperation->operator = $operator;
    $feedItemClassOperation->operand = $feedItemClass;

    $allOperations[] = $feedItemClassOperation;
}

if (!empty($allOperations)) {
    // Perform all operations at once
    $feedItemService->mutate($allOperations);
}
```

(1): https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201506/FeedService.FeedAttribute

Greetings.